# Restricting Window Maximization Size

Tags: fedora, window, conky

I am currently running Conky to display some text on my background on the far right of the screen.  The window is probably 200 pixels wide.

Is it possible that when I maximize a window, there is some setting to prevent the window from completely maximizing?  I have been manually adjusting the window size up until now.

E.g. My resolution is 1024 x 800 but when I maximize any window it should only maximize up to 824 x 800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the built in maximization can be adjusted, but a custom grid in the window management tool [Gridmove](http://jgpaiva.dcmembers.com/gridmove.html) could well do the job.

You may need a bit of work to make the custom grid but it would certainly be able to do what you are after.